# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest. Error appearing at startup

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, jakarta-migration

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
... 13 common frames omitted

I am getting this error while running the SpringBootApplication. The application is basically a simple graphql api application. I am unable to resolve this issue. Can someone help resolve this issue.

I tried adding the jakarta.servlet-api dependency but the error is persisting. I am unable to locate the source of the error.

Comment: This can happen when you deploy it as a WAR to an outdated server such as Tomcat 9 or older. The jakarta package is only supported since Tomcat 10. But this can also happen when you meddle too much with the default transitive dependencies of Spring Boot. In any case you should NOT be manually adding the servlet API dependency at all. This is supposed to be provided by the server already.